# Proxy sends multiply requests from ExtJs store

Tags: java, extjs

My app send multiply request to server each time I insert new item to store. When the first item inserted it calls POST once, one more item ... twice and so on.

Im new at ExtJs, so can you help me in solving some qustions:

1. First of all what the **sync** method do, why (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) methods are not called without store.sync() method invok?
2. Why my post method **multiply** requests?
3. Why store.remove() (DELETE) method throws 400 error (**Bad request**) when the PUT method works fine?

*Thank you in advance*

my edit controller:

```
Ext.define('MVC.controller.Edit', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',


init: function () {
    this.control({
        'editForm > button#SaveRecord': {
            click: this.onSaveButtonClick
        },
        'editForm > button#DeleteButton': {
            click: this.onDeleteButtonClick
        }
    });
},

onSaveButtonClick: function (btn) {
    //get reference to the form
    var detailView = btn.up('editForm');

    //get the form inputs
    var data = detailView.getValues();

    //see if the record exists
    var store = Ext.getStore('TestStore');
    console.log(data.id);
    var record = store.getById(data.id);

    if (!record) {
        record = Ext.create('MVC.model.Note', {
            title: data.title,
            created: new Date(),
            updated: new Date(),
            text: data.text
        });

        store.insert(0, record);
        store.sync();
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Created', record.id);
        return;
    }

    record.set(data);

    store.sync();
    //manually update the record
    detailView.updateRecord();
},

onDeleteButtonClick: function (btn) {

    //get reference to the form
    var detailView = btn.up('editForm');

    //get the form inputs
    var data = detailView.getValues();

    var store = Ext.getStore('TestStore');
    var record = store.getById(data.id);
    store.remove(record);
    store.sync();
}
});
```

Store :

```
Ext.define('MVC.store.TestStore', {
extend  : 'Ext.data.Store',

requires : [
    'MVC.model.Note'
],

storeId : 'TestStore',
model   : 'MVC.model.Note',
autoLoad: false,
proxy: {
    type : 'rest',
    url: 'rest/notes',
    actionMethods : {
        create  : 'POST',
        read    : 'GET',
        update  : 'PUT',
        destroy : 'DELETE'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'data'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json'
    }
}
});
```

And model:

```
Ext.define('MVC.model.Note', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields: [
    {
        name: 'id',
        type: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'title',
        type: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'created',
        type: 'date'
    },
    {
        name: 'updated',
        type: 'date'
    },
    {
        name: 'text',
        type: 'string'
    }
]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use record's methods:

1)Add proxy to you'r model like this:

```
Ext.define('MVC.model.Note',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields: [
{
    name: 'id',
    type: 'string'
},
{
    name: 'title',
    type: 'string'
},
{
    name: 'created',
    type: 'date'
},
{
    name: 'updated',
    type: 'date'
},
{
    name: 'text',
    type: 'string'
}],

proxy:
{
    type: 'rest',
    url: 'rest/notes',
    reader:
    {
        type: 'json'
    }
}
});
```

2)Now you can use methods: `record.save()` - will send **PUT** if it was loaded to store from server and record have id, or **POST** if this record was created with `record.create()`;
`record.destroy()` - will send **DELETE** to server with id of record;
You can use `Ext.ModelManager.getModel('Model_name').load(id)` to send **GET** request to server for single record.
3)Use `store.load()` to **GET** array of records from server